# Is it possible to clone a repository in an organization that is enabling 2 factor-authentication?

Tags: python, docker, github, package, two-factor-authentication

Is it possible to install a python package in GitHub(in an organization) that is enabling 2 factor-authentication into a docker container?

How can I write a dockerfile?

Comment: In general, I'd recommend avoiding `git` commands in Dockerfiles.  Managing credentials is tricky (even ignoring 2FA concerns, you don't want to leak an ssh private key into the image) and there are questions around which branch to use and around Docker layer caching.  It's usually easier to clone the repository on the host, and `COPY` things you need into the image.

Comment: Honestly, your question is way too vague. The answer is "Yes". And also "How can I write a dockerfile?" Answer: https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: Sorry the correct reference for "How can I write a dockerfile?" is https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: @DavidMaze, Thank you so much. Your explanation does make sense to me. I'll try `copy` if it keeps failing.